# Mongo C# - Where is FindOne?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm having trouble understanding how to do a `findOne` operation in the Mongo C# 2.4 driver.

I have a collection with just over 9.1 million, flat documents.  When I perform a `findOne` in Robomongo, the query takes 0 seconds, and returns the result I wanted.

In C#, this takes about 7-8 seconds.

At present I'm implementing a find one like so:

```
var result = await _collection.Find(filterDefinition).SingleAsync();
```

This takes between 7 and 8 seconds.

**Mongo Query - Find One - 0 seconds**

```
.findOne({ipFrom: { $lte: 1436497981 }, ipTo: { $gte: 1436497981 }});
```

**Mongo Query - Find - 7.4 seconds**

```
.find({ipFrom: { $lte: 1436497981 }, ipTo: { $gte: 1436497981 }});
```

I can't find a `FindOne` or `FindOneAsync` method on `IMongoCollection<>`, so I'm suspicious that `.Find(...).SingleAsync()` is just performing a mongo `find` function.  I can see that there are `FindOneAndUpdate`, `FindOneAndDelete`, and `FindOneAndReplace`, but no `FindOne`.

My filter definition I'm using for the query is as follows:

```
var filter = Builders<TLocationEntity>.Filter;

var filterDefinition = filter.And(
    filter.Lte("ipFrom", ipValue),
    filter.Gte("ipTo", ipValue)
);
```

Basically, what's the correct way to do a `findOne` in the C# driver?

Comment: Well "technically speaking" so is `.findOne()` in the shell, and every other API for that matter. And you could actually see this in the shell simply by typing `db.collection.findOne` without the parentheses `()`. This will show you that `.find()` is in fact the only actual call in the underlying API. If you want "apples with apples" you need to `.find({ipFrom: { $lte: 1436497981 }, ipTo: { $gte: 1436497981 }}).limit(1)` to basically compare the same thing.

Comment: @NeilLunn Fair enough, thanks!  It's been a good few years since I touched Mongo so I'm a little rusty!  Adding `.Limit(1)` to my `.Find()` method dramatically improves performance.

Comment: And that is basically what `.SingleAsync()` and the like are doing. So technically everything is just a "cursor modifier" applied to find. The API has undergone some changes to generally make this more consistent across languages.

Comment: @NeilLunn Looking at the source code for `SingleAsync`, it looks like it performs a `find.Limit(2)`, rather than a `find.Limit(1)`.  If I run my query with `.limit(2)` in the mongo shell, it takes about 8 seconds, vs 0 seconds if I change it to 1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Adding `Limit(1)` fixed it for me:

```
await _collection.Find(filterDefinition).Limit(1).SingleAsync();
```

I would have expected `.SingleAsync()` to perform a `Limit(1)` inside it, however it seems to perform a `.Limit(2)` instead.  This is enough to cause my query to go from 0 seconds to 8 seconds.

Comment: It is performing limit 2 in order to make sure there is only one element. If it only fetched one, it would not know whether there is more than one or not, as the purpose of `SingleAsync()` is to return one or throw. Try `FirstAsync()`